# Why cangjie code of 誤 is YRRVK?

Tags: input-methods

Why cangjie code of 誤 is YRRVK in the dictionary instead of YRRMK? Although both worked on my ime. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because in Traditional Chinese (the basis for cangjie) the 天 part is actually written like

```
|______
   |  /
___|___
  / \
 /   \
```

where the

```
|______
      /
```

parts give it the V (女) code

Comment: Thank you The Lyrist. You are great. I have found that in my dictionary in the drawing animation it actually wrote the right part of 誤 similar to the right part of 悞 ( that itself is a variant of 誤）.